# Word for "group of people who went through the same thing"

Tags: synonyms

I am making an app for communities and I need a word to describe when people attended the same class, went through a particular semester of the same program, were on the same cruise, attended the same club in college, were part of the same honors program for the same years etc.

Like *batch* or *cohort* but something that can describe all the above situations.

Alternatively, the word can describe the experience, eg they were part of the same ________. Program?

Comment: What's wrong with "cohort" (aside from the fact that nobody knows what it means any more)?

Comment: I was going to go with cohort, just sounds a bit esoteric, how about "batch"?

Comment: @GregoryMagarshak - Are you going to market this to people in the U.S., the UK, or somewhere else?

Comment: @aparente001 - both countries. Our app is used around the world. Primarily in the USA though.

Answer (score 1):

**"group"** fits all the situations described. (the very word has been used by the OP)

From [**TFD**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/group)

> - "a number of individuals or things considered or classed together because of similarities"
> - " a number of persons bound together by common social standards, interests, etc"
> - "a number of persons or things ranged or considered together as being related in some way."

e.g.

- A group of ecologists
- A group of hackers had planned to...
- We were a group of seven and our guide decided to...
- When I was in college, there were three foreign students in my group.
- I'm teaching a group of kids how to...
- Why don't we travel as a group?

Answer (score 1):

How about or **coterie** ?

From Dictionary.com:

> **coterie**: a group of people who associate closely.

I think you could describe "*people attended the same class, went through a particular semester of the same program, were on the same cruise, attended the same club in college, were part of the same honors program for the same years etc.*" as a **coterie**. It's of there same sort as "cohort".

Answer (score 1):

*Cohort* is better than *batch*.  But I understand your hesitation to use *cohort* for your particular purposes.  It might be a little off-putting.

Refugees that make a long trek together can be termed *trek mates*.  If the primary mode of travel is by boat, they call each other *boat-mates*.

If you've been studying together, you are *classmates*.  If you work together, you are *workmates* or *coworkers*.  If you share a house you are *housemates*.

Sorry for the tangent.  Now I will answer the question you actually asked.

*gang*

> They were part of the same **gang**.

From the context it will be clear that you're not talking underlife.

Comment: _Cohort_ is widely used in academia in that sense.

Comment: Yeah. Cohort is in #1 place for me so far, due to fitting everything. But it definitely seems a bit technical and unusual. I thought maybe there was some more "friendly" or "usual" word. Actually from what you said, "mates" may be the term? I might coin it in the app, but then you have class*mates*, ship*mates* as you said... with the benefit of the noun being right before the *mates*

Comment: *Mates* are the fellow group members.  *Gang* is the word I'm proposing for the group.  That was a clarification.  Now, to answer your question, "class", "ship", etc., don't matter very much.  However, it might be helpful to show them as examples when you are recruiting new subscribers.  (But not "ship" -- doesn't bring pleasant images to mind.)

Comment: Also note that in UK English, I believe *mate* is a synonym for "friend".  It's a word with a very positive vibe.  In your context, *gang* is too.  Think of the song that has the line "the gang's all here".  "Cohort" sounds way too technical.  You can use it as a data-name in your programming, but don't use it on your website.

Comment: In the UK, _mate_ is also very informal. _You alright, mate?_ is something you'd say to a stranger, and quite a few people don't like to be called _mate_.

Comment: @OliverMason - that's not the point.  OP's question has nothing to do with what one stranger might say to another at a train station.

Comment: @aparente001 It is the point. A lot of people don't like being called _mate_ by anybody.

Comment: @OliverMason - Are you saying it's such an unpleasant word that it would bother people to see a sentence like "Connect with your schoolmates, connect with your workout mates -- try this new app"?  Well, in that case, can you suggest a more positive word?  In the US one could say "work buddies" -- but I have a feeling that doesn't work in the UK.

Comment: @aparente001 In connection with _work-_ or _school-_ it seems fine, only _mate_ alone works that way. In the UK, _work buddies_ does indeed sound overly 'chummy'.

Comment: @OliverMason - and that leads us to a new possible answer, *chum*, *group of chums*.  I don't care for it myself, but maybe it would sound better in UK English....

Answer (score 0):

> singular *alumnus*.  (plural ***alumni***)
>   1 :  a person who has attended or has graduated from a particular school, college, or university
>   2 :  a person who is a former member, employee, contributor, or inmate
>
> — http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alumnus

Note: there is much discussion online about the male/female/singular/plural forms of this Latin-derived word which I am not going into here!

Also I think **alumni** is well enough understood so that it can be "stretched" beyond its traditional *graduate or former student* usage

Comment: This is good, but only for after people have gone through the same class, club or experience. While they are still in it, they aren't alums. They are _____? I know, you've answered my question, I am just asking for my app.